# Biblioteca Tkinter não é reconhecida pelo Pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou importando a biblioteca do Tkinter no PyCharm, porém o PyCharm não está reconhecendo suas funcionalidades, não executando e apresentando erro.

Anexei a imagem do erro apresentado para auxílio.

[image: foto do script que esta dando erro]

Answer (score 3):

Seu arquivo de chama `tkinter.py`.

Quando você faz `from tkinter import *`, você importará todos os objetos do seu próprio arquivo. Pela ordem de prioridade, o interpretador irá buscar pelo módulo primeiro no diretório do projeto.

Como seu arquivo não define a classe `Tk`, o erro de classe não definida é lançado.

Para evitar esses problemas, evite nomear seus arquivos com nomes de módulos do Python.

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo !!! eu não sabia que isto poderia dar conflito, bom vivendo e aprendendo e obrigado dnv !!!